Any solutions for fixing driver problem with the Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi network controller?
Today (04.06.2024) I used my lenovo yoga slim 7 pro running ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS for the first time since 02.06.2024. Everything worked as it was supposed to the last time, but now there is a issue with the network controller: "No WiFi adapter is found" in settings. So it would seem that a automatic update has broken the network drivers.
Here is some info about the network controller:
Running sudo lshw -C network gives:
Network controller
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601d1cc000-601d1cffff

and running lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 gives:
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

What I have tried:

Updated the network driver to its latest version both through snap store and using sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms from this post
Added the line: options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf from this post

None of the above worked.
